# Disabling selection of dates before specific date

Tags: php, html

[image]

I want that when user selects start date and end date then the dates before the start date selected would become disable in end date. I am using HTML5 input `type=date` for this. How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always validate things on a server-side level too, but without seeing your code it's kind of hard to guess what it looks like.

However, you can use the attribute `min="YYYY-mm-dd"` to specify the first valid day, and likewise for `max="YYYY-mm-dd"` would be the maximum available day to select.

You can use JavaScript to modify this on the fly, as an example

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="start" onChange='var end = document.getElementById("end"); end.setAttribute("min", this.value); end.value = (this.value);' />
<input type="date" id="end" name="end" />
```

This will set the attribute `min` of the `id="end"` to the value selected of `id=start`.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzgx976u/)**

Comment: This exactly did what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Datepicker then add **min** or **max** attribute to your **input type =date**. Your date must be in this **(yyyy-mm-dd)** format as well.